# SF Retag Request: [windows2000server] -> [windows-server-2000]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

(EDIT: changed the request based on Eric's answer)

To align to the convention we've created on SF.

12 questions currently tagged with [windows2000server]

15 tagged with [windows-2000-server]

Thanks!

BTW- I agree with hyperslug that a dozen bumps from me doing this manually is a bit noisy on the front page... I can do it, though, if nobody wants to.
([see this answer from earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23473/retag-request-videostreaming-video-streaming/23476#23476))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retag completed.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reasons for retagging seem to be either SEO or to merge two related subjects under the more appropriate of the two.  It seems to me that, here, the correct choice would be **[windows-2000-server]** as that matches the product name and, according to [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=%22windows+2000+server%22%2C+%22windows+server+2000%22&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0), is a far more popular search term than "windows server 2000".

Comment: That's a good point about the SEO and following Google Trends.  Works for me.  I'd still like the retag since it's to merge related tags together!